# jQuery Mobile - fixed headers

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a query mobile site and I am trying to keep my header fixed at the top of the page and have the content scroll underneath. In the documentation I found exactly how to do this.  Simply add data-position="fixed" attribute to the header element.  Easy enough and it looks great on their demo page ([Fixed Toolbars](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)).

However, when I do the exact same thing on my side, I get the ugly fading toolbars. The header is now fixed, which is good, but I would like it to be always visible (and not fade in and out when the user scrolls).

So my question is:  Is there an easy way to avoid the fading?  How did JQM avoid the fading on their own demo page?  I seem to not be able to see how they implement the behavior differently than I do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you testing in on Android device?

Comment: no, I am testing on an iPhone. Is the behavior device dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing my headers in CSS using `position: fixed;`

I know iPhones with iOS < 5 can't handle it, but I am OK with that.

Comment: there would also be a polyfill for iOS<5, which brings back the fade in/out behavior on older devices. So iOS5+ will be true fixed, iOS<5 will have the fixed fade in/out. here is the link: https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Mobile-FixedToolbar-Legacy-Polyfill

Answer (score 1):

**Theres a new JQuery Mobile release out**

The new version of [JQuery Mobile 1.1.0](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/#features) includes improved support for fixed header positioning so you no longer need to specify CSS `position: fixed`.

One note however, I've tried JQM 1.1.0 and found the following:

- iOS 5+ -: Works great
- iOS 4 and below - No support for fixed header (scrolls away with your page)
- Android 2.3 + : Works great (make sure you disable page scaling using meta tag)
- Android 2.2: Header jumps up and down the page
- Android 2.1 and below: No support for fixed headers.

This has to do with the underlying support for CSS fixed positioning on the browser.

There is a good but 8 years old article on:
[http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the jquery positon:fixed in my headers, it still works well on Android 2.x.x but on Android 4+ it still junps on and off and make it unusable.

The CSS way indeed works properly.