# Fixed Header & Footer not working in JqueryMobile

Tags: android, html

I am developing a hybrid mobile app for Android. I am using jquerymobile 1.2.0 as the framework. I want to have my header and footer fixed while the contents in the body segment will be scrolling vertically for which am using the data-role="listview".

But the problem is the header and the footer are also scrolling up with the body scroll.

- My Notes
- My Queries
- eLearning
- Assignment
- Media
- Broadcast

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
        <li>
        <img src="images/noprofileimg.jpg" />
                    <h3>Indraneel Roy <small>says</small></h3>
        <p >Friday, October 8, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count">2</span></p>
        <p>@abir kab h freshears ???</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!--end of body container-->
```

Copyright © company name 2012-2013.
All Rights Reserved.

Can you please tell me where or what am I doing wrong

Comment: <div data-role="page" id="home" class="ui-page" >
 <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="false" data-tap-toggle="false" class="headerBg borderBottom">
    
    </header>
    
    <div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
   <li>

   </li>
  </ul>
 </div><!--end of body container-->
    
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="false" data-tap-toggle="false">
<h6 class="fl">Copyright &copy; company name 2012-2013.<br/>All Rights Reserved.</h6>
</div>

This is code for the problem

Comment: Have you checked this question out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269663/jquery-mobile-fixed-headers

Comment: Hi Niclas,

Yes I had seen that but dnt helped. Another problem is that the header and footer scrolls up but when I tap the body once after that both the header & footer becomes fixed and only the body content scrolls

Answer (score 2):

Did you disable viewport scaling? It's one of the most common issues in Android that makes position:fixed not working... e.g.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

also check out this excellent but 8 years old post regarding android HTML5 scrolling issues:
https://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

But first add correct viewport meta tag to the head section of your html and see if this helps..

Comment: I am facing same issue on Android 4+. Adding 'position:fixed' makes footer disappear. Could please share, how you have resolved this issue.

Comment: was using meta tag without last two items "maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no", adding those fixed that issue for me, thx!